# Is Cairo-dock full compatible after installation of amd driver with The fan club website

Tags: drivers, ati, compatibility, cairo-dock

I have installed on my Ubuntu 12.04. LTS, the version beta for the amd driver ( AMD
Radeon HD 7650M) with the website tool The Fan Club (http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/ubuntu-amd-catalyst-install) and I have observed that the Cairo-dock is not more working.
(nothing happens in the dash when I click on it). So I reinstalled the release
version of amd driver and for this case, I got an error when I start cairo-dock. I
have seen on the website of AMD catalyst
http://support.amd.com/ja-jp/kb-articles/Pages/Latest-LINUX-Beta-Driver.aspx that
normally the problem for cairo-dock support is solved. In my case, this beta version
seems to do not work for cairo. Could you explain me the reason? Is it really the
last beta version? Thank a lot for your help and support.

Answer (score 0):

BETA version of any software means its not completed its development and its in still testing.
The active volunteers will test the BETA releases and they will report to developers about their problem or BUG.

**what you have to do ?**

If you want to fix your issue you'd better contact the particular and you report your issue. If you contact them they will guide you on how to report.

Hope that helps.